# position absolute child box same size as parents box mirror images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two boxes and the smaller box needs to be the same size as the parent's parent box but the problem is that the box is in position absolute, so what is happing is that it is stopping me from making the child box as large as the parent. I'm trying to mirror two boxes that have the same image. One of these images is going to be blurred but the images must be on the same scale as each other. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvc5x34z/)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#banner {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/glare_rainbow_circles_background_20329_1440x900.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box:before {
  background-image: url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/glare_rainbow_circles_background_20329_1440x900.jpg);
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvc5x34z/)

Comment: not clear what you want, you are setting the size of the box, so make it the same as parent using 100%

Comment: I want to mirror the image in the small box to the some scale

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for masking

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#banner {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/glare_rainbow_circles_background_20329_1440x900.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}


#banner:before {
  content:"";
  background:inherit;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  filter:grayscale(80%);
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center/200px 100px no-repeat;
          mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center/200px 100px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
 
</div>
```

Or `background-attachment:fixed;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#banner {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/glare_rainbow_circles_background_20329_1440x900.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  margin:auto;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box:before {
  background-image: url(https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/glare_rainbow_circles_background_20329_1440x900.jpg);
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  filter:grayscale(80%);
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="box">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your second example is almost right but I don't want to just center the box I want to put the box where ever I want can you adjust your code to do that?

Comment: @ONYX simply adjust the position like you want of `.box` and in the first example change `center` with any value you want

Comment: It doesn't work when you place .box anywhere on the document the image doesn't line up could you please try another example

Comment: @ONYX it does work using the first method: https://jsfiddle.net/qc8tv0jo/1/ and the second one:  https://jsfiddle.net/qc8tv0jo/2/

Comment: It's not the way I want it, I want to position box anywhere I want, I want it centered but 25% from the top and it's not a mask

Comment: And to center horizontall you cannot use transform transforms because it affects the image

Comment: @ONYX you don't need to use transform and you can position the element where you want: https://jsfiddle.net/qw6re9h0/ .. still don't see what the issue. Also with the first method:  https://jsfiddle.net/6apm74sh/